# How to get index from GMSMarker tapped?

Tags: swift, google-maps

How to detect which marker was pressed on a map. I have few markers on map and class Marker in markers array downloaded from API, that contains some data.

for example i have data like this

```
[States(name: "text1", long: 110.42400399999997,lat: -7.0343237999999992), 
States(name: "text2", long: 110.42769829999997, lat: -7.0856947999999997), 
States(name: "text3", long: 110.42922440000007, lat: -7.3250846999999997), 
States(name: "text4", long: 117.11625830000003, lat: -0.50436380000000003), 
States(name: "text5", long: 110.43093620000002, lat: -7.0730081999999994)]
```

if i tap on marker that contain data 1 (`States(name: "text1", long: 110.42400399999997,lat: -7.0343237999999992)`)

How do i get index 0. and if i tap on marker that contain data 2, How do i get index 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I suppose you added the markers by iterating through the array like this:

```
for state in states { // assuming states is the array you showed in the question
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: state.lat, longitude: state.long))
    // configure the marker...
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

The idea is that you add the markers to an array as well, just after you created it. Since you created the markers in the order of the data, each item in the array containing the markers corresponds to the data at the same index.

Let's declare the array of markers at class level:

```
var markers = [GMSMarker]()
```

Then in the for loop above, add the marker to `markers`:

```
markers.append(marker)
```

Now you can find out which datum is tapped just by:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    if let index = markers.index(of: marker) {
        let tappedState = states[index]
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Thanks! It Works!

Comment: Does the tap follows the sequence, in which the markers been added ?

Comment: @Sweeper :  Does the tap on GSMMarker  follows the same sequence, in which the markers been added ?

Comment: @VinayMaheshwari The user can tap on the markers in any order they like, can't they?

Comment: @Sweeper : All my markers on same location (Same lat,lon). For example user does 4 events at same location but on different times. I want to show the information (Marker Info window) order by event time.

Comment: @VinayMaheshwari I don't think that has anything to do with this question. I suggest you post a question.

Comment: @Sweeper I raised the question earlier, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639907/ios-mutiple-gmsmarker-for-same-location-been-added-in-a-sequence-will-the-tap . I thought you might have answer for that. But thanks for your time.